# Launch aws cli commands from jmeter

Tags: jmeter, aws-cli

I am trying to use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to run the `aws cli` commands in JMeter. 
I will be running this on docker where JMeter and `aws cli` both will be installed. But before I can do that, I tried to run this locally on my mac but so far unable to get the aws command to run.

On my local terminal for eg I can run: 
a. aws --version 
b. bash j.sh (aws --version)
Both returns aws-cli/2.0.8 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/2.0.0dev12

This confirms aws cli is available in path to be accessible globally.

However when I run the same command from OS Process sampler, I have tried following:
a.

```
Working Directory: /Users/tester/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin
Environment: {}
Executing: bash aws --version
```

[image]

RESPONSE: `bash: aws --version: No such file or directory`

b.

```
Working Directory: /Users/tester
Environment: {}
Executing: bash j.sh
where j.sh just contains the aws --version command
```

[image]

RESPONSE: `j.sh: line 1: aws: command not found`

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks Vadim for your help with editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Dmitri and Vadim for your response on my question. Unfortunately both examples are for Windows where OS Process sampler will work differently compared to Mac. I got it to work with few more tweaks using OS Process Sampler on Mac as well:

[image]

The key difference for Mac is that jmeter needs the location aws cli is installed

```
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

I was able to find this via which command

```
which aws
```

I also decided to use Beanshell sampler along with logging to do this which will allow me to script and control better my other needs. 
Here is my reference code that works:

```
try {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/aws --version");
    p.waitFor();


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder logCommandOutput = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        logCommandOutput.append(line);
    } in .close();
    log.info("Output: " + logCommandOutput.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("exception" + e);

}
```

Hope this helps someone who is trying to do the same.

Comment: Have you test it in docker too? What OS are you going to use in Docker to run this test?

Comment: Hi Vadim, I will be using debian linux. I ran the test on docker, didn't see any errors. But need to sort out the aws profile on the container to try more of the aws commands to see if its really working.

Answer (score 2):

For those who need to run AWS CLI v2 commands from JMeter **on Windows** (I use 10).
Below is my setup.

[image]

the original command is:

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to configure your [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) as follows:

- Command: `/bin/bash`
- Parameter 1: `-c`
- Parameter 2: `aws --version`

  [image]

Demo:

[image]

From [bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> `-c`        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from
>                    the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are
>                    arguments after the command_string, the first argument is
>                    assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to
>                    the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the
>                    name of the shell, which is used in warning and error
>                    messages.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, this possibly will work on Windows. On Mac I couldn't get this to work. What worked on Mac was below:
Command: /usr/local/bin/aws 
Command parameters: --version

Answer (score 1):

To run aws cli command in JMeter:

1. Add [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to your test plan.
2. In the `Command` field enter your command: `aws`.
3. In the `Command Parameters` add any parameters you need, for example this one: `--version`.

[image]

4. Add a View Results Tree to your Thread Group, run the test and see response body:

   `aws-cli/2.0.0 Python/3.7.5 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev4`